# How to compare to spread argument?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How do I compare values of spread argument with some value?

For example:

```
var arr = [1, 4, 10];

if(Math.min(...arr) > 1) {
  console.log('Must be greater than 1');
}
```

is giving me `undefined`. Naturally same with `Math.max(...arr)`.

Same happens if I do:

```
var val = Math.min(...arr);
```

and then compare variable with some value.

Why?

Comment: Your posted code works...

Comment: Maybe you're testing this in an environment where spread operators aren't supported.

Comment: It doesn't.. 

`var arr = [1, 4, 10];

if(Math.min(...arr) > 1) {
  console.log('Must be greater than 1');
}
undefined`

Comment: @Cynigo, I'm testing this in console right now.

Comment: You're probably not running in browser that supports ES6 spread syntax. Alternatively, you can use `Math.min.apply(null, arr);` and `Math.max.apply(null, arr);`

Comment: your code works fine. https://jsfiddle.net/c9L9ae41/

Comment: Based on your `console.log` message, shouldn't it be `if(Math.min(...arr) <= 1) {`?

Comment: Oh well, the function you're using doesn't return anything, hence the undefined. And since you're condition isn't met, it won't print anything either. Try replacing the `console.log('...');` with `return '...';`

Comment: @tholo Depending on what console you're using, it could be wrapping your code in an IIFE, and logging the return value (which in this case is undefined).

Comment: @mhodges, Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit) - Chrome inspect, default.

Comment: Yeah.. sorry about that.

Comment: [`...` is not an operator!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508)

Comment: FWIW, you are not comparing 1 to the return value of `Math.min()`, not the spread "operator".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The logic is wrong.

```
var arr = [1, 4, 10];

if(Math.min(...arr) <= 1) {   
  console.log('Must be greater than 1'); 
}
```

Comment: Oh God... I can't believe I asked this dumb question. 14 hours of coding gives you this. Sorry for taking the time of you all... I can't delete the question.

Comment: @tholo Question should be closed as a "Typographical error"

Comment: @mhodges, yeah.. flagged...